# BDO - How do I get more lodging for my workers?

Tags: black-desert-online

I got a scroll titled, "Contract: Naive Worker". When I right-click on it, it gives me the error: "Not enough lodging for workers to stay in."

How do I get more lodging for my workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first worker that you hire within a node requires no lodging. However, to hire a second worker, you must obtain lodging for that worker to stay in.

To rent a house which you can use as lodging for workers: Open the world map and click on the town you'd like to buy lodging in. Select a blue house, and select the lodge function. Click the accept button and it will deduct the Contribution Points and a house conversion fee. It will also take some time to do this, you can see how long before you start the job.

Comment: Ok, I looked a bit harder and found that some houses didn't have the "Lodging" option available. I guess you have to find the right house for it, so not just any house will do.

Comment: @AlberBori , I would like ot mention as well, citys are the best place to have workers (Calpheon, Heidel etc) but towns (Tarif/Trent/Western Guard post etc) also provid lodging spaces as well, there are a few of the other nodes, mainly trade nodes that have houses that can support workers